# Subscribing action server message

Tags: control, ros, gazebo, gripper, kinova

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am trying to simulate the Kinova Mico arm in a Gazebo simulation. I have everything working, executing paths calculated in Moveit. The only thing I have yet to simulate is the gripper. I am using the [wpi_jaco package](http://wiki.ros.org/wpi_jaco) to communicate with the hardware arm, that we also have here. It uses an action server to actuate the fingers.
It sends a control_msgs::GripperCommandActionGoal message to the goal topic.

What I want is to also receive the message and then convert the wanted position to an angle which I can publish to the controller topic. I wrote a normal subscriber to the topic but this isn't working. When building I get this error.

```
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value(const M&) [with M = double]’: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message_traits.h:255:104:   required from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum(const M&) [with M = double]’ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:   required from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = double]’ /home/laurens/catkin_ws/src/mico_sim/mico_arm_gazebo/src/gazebo_rviz.cpp:95:35:   required from here /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message_traits.h:126:34: error: request for member ‘__getMD5Sum’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const double’
 return m.__getMD5Sum().c_str();
```

How can I make it work? It is kind of urgent, so if someone can put me on the right track, I would be thankful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236884/subscribing-action-server-message/) by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved the issue. Had to do with data types not matching. A std_msgs::Float cannot be assigned to a normal float. Also had to specify the float.data in order to write to it.

---

Originally posted by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) with karma: 167 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0